# Package is not existing in android studio

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I use maven to import library

```
implementation 'com.arxanfintech:wallet-sdk-java:2.0.1c'
```

When it completed

`Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8dVR.png)

Comment: you have an error in MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, you should add `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'` in the dependencies